# How to get all groups that a user is a member of, based on group extensionattribute

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

I'm tryng to get all the groups the users of a domain are member of, but filtering only the groups with a given **extensionattribute**.
I set the **extensionattribute12** of all the domain groups to better filter some queries (i.e. Infrastructure - security - elearning). My query should get only the user(s) groups with

> extensionattribute12=security

(for example).
I use something like:

```
get-aduser -filter  -Properties memberof | select name, @{ l="GroupMembership"; e={$_.memberof  -join ";"  } }
```

and I get all the groups of the users. How can I filter by group extensionattribute?

Comment: Do you only need direct group memberships or should it resolve indirect group memberships as well?

Comment: Hi. You mean nested groups? No, only direct group membership.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the inverse relationship (`member` on the group object) to query all the groups a user is a member of, just 1 query per user. Here using an LDAP filter:

```
$groupLabel = "Security"

Get-ADUser -Filter * |ForEach-Object {
  $groups = Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(&(extensionattribute12=$groupLabel)(member=$($_.DistinguishedName)))"

  [pscustomobject]@{
    User = $_.SamAccountName
    GroupMembership = $groups.DistinguishedName -join ';'
  }
}
```

---

If you have to process a large number of users or group memberships, you may find it faster to retrieve all the groups satisfying the `extensionAttribute12` criteria up front and use that list to filter the `memberOf` attribute on the users:

```
$groupLabel = "Security"
# Create a hash set and populate it with the distinguished 
# names of all the groups we're looking for
$groupDNs = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new(@(
  Get-ADGroup -Filter "extensionAttribute12 -eq '$groupLabel'" |Select -Expand DistinguishedName
))

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties memberOf |ForEach-Object {
  # Retrieve memberOf values and filter against the hash set
  $groups = $_.memberOf |Where-Object { $groupDNs.Contains($_) }

  [pscustomobject]@{
    User = $_.SamAccountName
    GroupMembership = $groups -join ';'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make it with N+1 queries

```
$groups = @( Get-ADGroup -Filter '(extensionattribute12 -eq "security")' )
$users = @( $groups | 
    ForEach-Object { Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $_ -Recursive } | 
    Sort-Object -Unique )

$users # All users of all groups that have EA12 = security
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-ADUser -filter {...} -Properties memberof | select name, @{ l="GroupMembership"; e={( $_.memberof | Get-ADGroup |?{ $_.extensionattribute12 -eq 'security' }) -join ";" }} |?{ $_.GroupMembership }
```

Comment: Nice job, it is better if you add some context about your code